# General Rules for Group Structure using Sylow's Theorems

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Say I have a group G such that |G|=20. Then by Sylow's Theorems there can be  or 4 Sylow 3-groups and 1 or 3 Sylow 4-groups. The case of 1 Sylow 3-group and 1-Sylow 4 group is trivial, but I have no clue how to continue. Also can you give general rules about how to find the group structure given Sylow's theorems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you write something down wrongly? There are no elements of order 3 in a 20-element group, and there are elements of order 5.

Comment: Sound like you need to read (or reread) you text.  In the event you reply "I read it...but",  I Googled for you: [Sylow Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems); you'll find examples, and general rules.

Answer (score 2):

By the Sylow theroems there are some number of $5-$groups and some number of $4-$groups

The number of 5 groups is equal to $1$ mod $5$  And there can't be 6 of them, because that would take up more elements than you have in the group.

There is one 5-group.  Since there is only one, and all Sylow groups are conjugates of one another, it is a normal subgroup.

There must be an odd number of 4-groups.
but they could be cyclic 4 groups, or they could resemble $K_4$